# PYSNMP: pyasn1.error.SubstrateUnderrunError: 37998-octet short

Tags: python, pysnmp

I have python version 4.3.2, py2exe 0.9.1.0, pysnmp 0.4.3.1, pyans1 0.1.9.
Im encountering all type of inconsistent errors in many different clients.
One of my clients, which has hundreds of SNMP devices, consonantly has pysnmp errors that are preventing him from discovering all snmp devices.
This is the function:

```
def cbFun_Device(transportDispatcher, transportDomain, transportAddress, wholeMsg):
    while wholeMsg:
        for ip in Device.scan.devices:
            if ip == transportAddress[0]:
                try:
                    PDU = Device.scan.devices[ip].PDU
                    rspMsg, wholeMsg = decoder.decode(wholeMsg, asn1Spec = PDU['pMod'].Message())
                    rspPDU = PDU['pMod'].apiMessage.getPDU(rspMsg)
                    # Match response to request
                    if PDU['pMod'].apiPDU.getRequestID(PDU['reqPDU']) == PDU['pMod'].apiPDU.getRequestID(rspPDU):
                        errorStatus = PDU['pMod'].apiPDU.getErrorStatus(rspPDU)
                        if not (errorStatus and errorStatus != 2):
                            PDUarr = []
                            varBindTable = PDU['pMod'].apiPDU.getVarBindTable(PDU['reqPDU'], rspPDU)
                            for tableRow in varBindTable:
                                for oid, val in tableRow:
                                    print('from: %s, %s = %s' % (transportAddress, oid.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
                                    if str(oid.prettyPrint()) not in Device.scan.params['MIBs']:
                                        for mibOID in PDU['MIBs']:
                                            if str(oid.prettyPrint()).find(mibOID) != -1 and mibOID not in Device.scan.devices[ip].MIBs:
                                                Device.scan.devices[ip].MIBs.append(mibOID)
                                    for tree in PDU['OIDs']:
                                        if str(oid.prettyPrint()).find(tree) != -1 and str(oid.prettyPrint()) not in Device.scan.devices[ip].OIDs:
                                            Device.scan.devices[ip].OIDs[str(oid.prettyPrint())] = val.prettyPrint()[:-1][2:] if val.prettyPrint().startswith("b'") and val.prettyPrint().endswith("'") else val.prettyPrint()
                                            PDUarr.append((str(oid.prettyPrint()), PDU['pMod'].null))
                            # Stop on EOM
                            for oid, val in varBindTable[-1]:
                                if not isinstance(val, PDU['pMod'].Null):
                                    break
                            else:
                                Progress.networks[ip]['Done'] = True
                                print("IP-------- " + ip)
                                Progress.progress.append(1)
                                Device.transportDispatcher.jobFinished(1)
                                continue    
                            # Generate request for next row
                            print(PDUarr)
                            if PDUarr != []:
                                PDU['pMod'].apiPDU.setVarBinds(PDU['reqPDU'], PDUarr)
                                PDU['pMod'].apiPDU.setRequestID(PDU['reqPDU'], PDU['pMod'].getNextRequestID())
                                Device.transportDispatcher.sendMessage(
                                    encoder.encode(PDU['reqMsg']), transportDomain, transportAddress
                                    )
                                Progress.networks[ip]['Time'] = time.time()
                            else:
                                Progress.networks[ip]['Done'] = True
                                print("IP-------- " + ip)
                                Progress.progress.append(1)
                                Device.transportDispatcher.jobFinished(1)
                                continue
```

And this is the error i receive:

```
37998-octet short
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\device.py", line 137, in cbFun_Device
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 706, in __call__
pyasn1.error.SubstrateUnderrunError: 37998-octet short
```

And sometimes this error too:

```
  pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: Empty substrate
```

but all errors happen on this line:

```
rspMsg, wholeMsg = decoder.decode(wholeMsg, asn1Spec = PDU['pMod'].Message())
```

What is going on?

Comment: You should definitely split that monster method into several functions and make it more readable.

Comment: Think question is less relevant to the function and more to the error. Can you explain me the meaning of the error and why im getting it.

Comment: I'm not into asn but the notion of 'substrate' in the context of the codec's stream means, that either no data or insufficient data to decode the original message.  See this: http://www.red-bean.com/doc/python-pyasn1/pyasn1-tutorial.html

Comment: That error can be caused by malformed/non-SNMP packets coming into your function. The other possibility is that you run your script in multiple threads without proper locking. In either case that is unlikely a pysnmp/pyasn1 issue to deal with.